# Is there a word for a person of love?

Tags: single-word-requests

They're a person that believes in everyone loving everyone. Advocates for everyone caring about and respecting each other.

Comment: Well, a "pacifist" is someone who opposes war, so that might be it?

Comment: @RileyFrancisco Nah, I can love you completely and still want you dead.  That way we can be together forever.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no context at all to help choose an ideal word or phrase.

Answer (score 0):

[Universal Lover](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/pagan-songs-and-chants-universal-lover-lyrics.html)

> You are my Mother, you are my Father
>
> You are my lover, you are my friend
>
> You're the beginning, you are the center
>
> And you are beyond the end
>
> ...

Maybe hippy.  Or Jesus.  Though, some think he was a hippy. :-)

Comment: +1 for hippy- that's what came to me first.  Not so sure about "Universal Lover" though.

Answer (score 0):

If you define "love" as kindness and benevolence, then the word **humanitarian** fits. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanitarianism):

> *Humanitarianism* is a moral of kindness, benevolence, and sympathy extended to all human beings.

However just like *philanthropy* it is used nowadays more to describe someone's deeds rather than attitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following words

***[benevolent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/benevolent)***

> characterized by or expressing goodwill or kindly feelings

***[benign](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/benign?s=t)***

> having a kindly disposition; gracious

[Dictionary.com]

There are other synonymous words to the above like :

- compassionate
- altruistic
- humble

and so on...